# Assembly division why is the overflow written into quotient location?

Tags: assembly

I start learning x86 assembly and attempt to write a division that would look like

```
int a,b,c,d,e
// doing some stuff, variables will all be 32 bit
a = ((b+c)-(d+e)) / 10
```

So writing an equivalent in assembly i came up with a little help from an video tutorial and this

```
.comm a, 4
.comm b, 4
.comm c, 4
.comm d, 4
.comm e, 4

//add b + c
movl b, %ebx
addl c, %ebx

// add d + e
movl d, %edx
addl e, %edx

// substract (d+e) from (b+c)
subl %edx, %ebx

// clear edx, and put result into eax for division
movl $0, %edx
movl %ebx, %eax

divl $10

// put the result to var a in memory
movl %eax, a

// also put the overflow into var a in mem?
// isnt the overflow overwriting my result in memory?
movl %edx, a
```

So in the last 2 lines, where the result is written back to memory. Why isnt the result simply replaced by the overflow, thats also written to the same location. The result from %eax is 4 bytes, is written to mem location a. After that, the overflow, also 4 bytes is written to the same memory location as my result. I am relatively new to assembly so i think im missing something essential. Please edit my question title, i really couldnt find a better one.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video you used? Yes `movl %edx, a` is overwriting the value stored in `a` in the previous instruction `movl %eax, a` so that is a problem

Comment: Should also point out `divl $10` isn't valid usage of the div instruction. It takes a register or memory operand but not an immediate value like `$10` . See http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html

Comment: `EDX` doesn't contain the overflow, it contains the remainder ("modulo"). For example, 44/10 = 4 with a remainder of 4.

Comment: A couple other observations. `subl %edx, %ebx` is %ebx-%edx result stored in %ebx. Your code actually does (d+e)-(b+c) . You have it backwards. Since you are using `div` this is unsigned division, but in your _C_ code you seem to be using `int` which is signed. Your assembler code won't deal with negative number properly on your division.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, i found the video here https://youtu.be/bQNZ4CwK-KY?t=1h4m4s I put the link with a timestamp. So is he teaching it wrong and should i find another source?

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, yes i meant the modulo, not the overflow. But theres also no sense for me in overwriting the result by the modulo.